# AWS cross account s3 bucket policy issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have three accounts -> accountA, accountB, accountC..

- I have an s3 bucket in accountB -> `archive/migration`
- accountA and accountC have access to this accountB S3 bucket and folder via bucket policy.
- From accountA I did `aws sync` a folder (`folder1`) to  `archive/migration` and set the `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` flag as well.
- when I check the `aws s3api get-object-acl` from accountA, I see the accountB has `FULL_CONTROL` on the newly synced folder `folder1`.
- Now I have an EC2 instance which is in accountC and has an IAM role, which has security policy to all actions on the `archive/migration`.. But when I do `get-object on a file in the folder, I get access denied`.. What am I doing wrong ? In this scenario , what should be the setup so that ec2 instance in account C has access to folders in s3 bucket in accountB , but the folders were created by account A.

Comment: Can you provide the policy code?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the Bucket Policy on the bucket in Account B.